# Exchange Object Serialization in Camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel

Can we make exchange object in camel as serializable ?

Let's say i want to cache the Exchange object as value in memcached, how to do that ? Memcached accepts values only if they are serializable objects !

TIA

Comment: Why would you want to put the whole exchange into memcached?

Comment: From the Camel routes, i would be calling Multiple Mid-Tier-Services(Http Calls) - and aggregate the exchanges from them. So cache the exchange objects from these http calls and use that if it is available in cache instead of making a a network call.. This is what i thought.. Please correct me if anything wrong here.. Would love to hear suggestions.

Comment: It isn't memcached, but there is a cache component available for Camel. If an EHCache would be acceptable it would be a more straight-forward option. See http://camel.apache.org/cache.html for more details. At the very least, it gives you an outline to how you *might* use memcached.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange is not serializable because objects that we put in exchange may not be always serializable. End users of Camel can put any kind of non serializable data in it.

Read more @ http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultExchangeHolder.html

Do not put entire Exchange object in cache memory ,instead Try to put only required object or else take a look at DefaultExchangeHolder

Comment: Yes, Sure. i will try with this.. Thanks